# Android surrounding box dimensions of the notification icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-notifications

I can't seem to find this information anywhere. I created a custom layout for my notification via RemoteViews but I can't find the dimensions of the surrounding are around the icon.

The following Android guidelines describe only the dimensions of the icon since its assuming I'm going to me using the notification builder to construct my notification:
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

[image: I'm looking for the box size around the icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "1U" notification format, the container is 64dp tall.

If you use "4U" Big Content notification, the container is 256dp tall but the icon remains at 64dp tall after the "expansion".

Normally the smallest staus icon is 24dp*24dp recommended, but nothing is officially documented about the big icon. If you want the best resolution you can try using squared bitmaps up to 64dp wich it seems the highest size that official Google apps offer.

Edited: Sorry, official doc is only talking about the tiny icon and confused me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yea, I couldn't find anything official. Also, depending on device launchers it always looks different (specially the samsung launcher).